# About clothes for a High to Low Poly pipeline

Tags: modeling, unity, polycount

I need clarification since I've done a high to low poly process before but now there's a new problem that complicates things for me slightly.

How I would do a character is make the high poly with all the details (clothes included) and then retopologize it, clothes included, as one full mesh. Then with the retopologized mesh, I'd bake a normal of the high poly.

But the problem is that this works only for one costume of this character.

Now I'm thinking of a different pipeline for interchangeable clothes. So it'd be the same character. I'd do the high poly of the naked character. But then I'd also need to do clothes over this high poly naked base mesh. That leads me to--

1. How do I sculpt the high polys and do retopos of clothes over a naked character?
2. What is the UV mapping process considering it's no longer just one mesh but several different ones like the head, hat, shirt, pants, boots, etc. ?
3. I'd like it to be possible to iterate or add new clothes whenever a new idea comes up or if problems arise.

Sorry for the noobish question. I've found several low to high poly workflows but not for high to low. Let me know if there's any other solutions or if my reasoning is incorrect. Thank anyone for their times for helping.

Comment: I think I dont follow quite well. You want to retopo a hi-poly mesh to a low-poly one but before use the character as a "collision" object when sculpting to prefent the dress go-thru???

Comment: I want to make a high poly mesh for a character as a "naked" mesh. Then I want to also have other high poly meshes around that mesh (Clothes, hat, etc.) before retopologizing all those separate objects. How would I go about that?

Comment: You want to make that clothes **on the naked mesh** (using its shapes) or just **around it**? Probably the easiest way to make clothes in Blender is using part of the source mesh (ie naked) and make tweaks needed or build the basic shape, fill with (a LOT of) polys and use the Shrinkwrap modifier. Check this for 2nd method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szEeu6_b4fg

Comment: Yes, I'd like to put the clothes around it, so as to be able to customize and change from one shirt to another, for example. Also, interesting video, it looks like a quick way to do clothes from what I briefly saw.

Comment: The important info I need is **will You use the base-mesh (naked) during the modeling of the clothes?**. If the answer is YES then use the Shrinkwrap, if NO then use standard techniques.

Comment: Yup! I think Shrinkwrap/ what the video you linked is exactly what I'd like to do. Thank you.

Comment: You are quite welcome Near! Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zNAATDadJc ...and happy Blending!!!